# Save Image into a file in C++

Tags: c++, image, file, save, sfml

I want to save an image into a custom file, in order to secure all images of my program.

I tried to save every pixels (as Uint32) of an image like this (I am using SFML)

```
void fromPNGtoCustomFile(sf::Texture texture, std::string path)
{
    std::ofstream fo; 
    fo.open(path);

    sf::Image image=texture.copyToImage(); //GET IMAGE OF THE TEXTURE

    fo << image.getSize().x << " " << image.getSize().y << " "; // WRITE THE SIZE OF THE IMAGE

    for(unsigned int i=0; i< image.getSize().x; i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j=0; j< image.getSize().y; j++)
        {
            fo << image.getPixel(i, j).toInteger() << " "; 

            // image.getPixel(x, y).toInteger() RETURNS A Uint32 VALUE
        }
    }


    fo.close();
}
```

Then I load image from the file using the same logic.

It worked, but I realised that the size of the file I created was around 250 Mb, when my original .png image was only 8 Mb. If I compress the new file using 7Zip, I get a 8 Mb file, as the original size. I do not understand why I get this size.

I don't really know what is the best way to create custom file for saving images.

Do you have any suggestions, or correction of my code?

Comment: What exactly about compression which you do not understand? Png files are compressed.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is here. Your code is very inefficient, but it's not incorrect. So what do you want exactly?

Comment: Well, I have a folder named 'ressources' which store all images of my program. I don't want anybody to steal them, so I want to create a custom file and kind of 'encrypt' datas of images. I don't know if my question is clear

Comment: @Peanut_Butcher In what way does the code above not achieve that? I'm still puzzled what you are expecting from us (which is what my last comment meant really).

Comment: If your concern is encryption then why not use an encryption library (libcrypt for instance), save the image in jpeg format but encrypted.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question of why you are getting such a big file size, it's because you are writing the information for every single pixel independently, so your file ends up as large as it can be. In order to reduce the size, the compressed formats take advantage of, for instance, the fact that there is usually a large number of neighbouring pixels that are the same colour. For example, an image of the sky will very likely contain an immense amount of pixels of the same shade of blue. So what you need to do is to define an algorithm with some sort of special code to denote that "the next N pixels are *some RGB colour*" or something to that effect.

A good source on data compression for images is on this chapter of the DSP Guide: http://www.dspguide.com/ch27.htm

Comment: Thank you, I will try this!